# Duplicate Photos In OneDrive

Tags: 8.1, onedrive, photos, lumia-icon

Many of my pictures on OneDrive are being duplicated. They only show up once on my phone, but if I visit OneDrive via [the website](https://onedrive.live.com/) or [the app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/onedrive/ad543082-80ec-45bb-aa02-ffe7f4182ba8?signin=true) many of my photos show up twice. Not all of them are duplicated, and I can't find any rhyme or reason for why it duplicates the ones it does. Has anyone else noticed this / found a fix?

Comment: Could it be that you're seeing different resolutions for each photo?

Comment: I don't think so. Because if I snap two pictures in a row (of different objects, of course), it will only duplicate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out the problem. It seems to happen with photos I've shared. It seems some of the apps will re-save the photo, therefore making it show up twice on OneDrive.